# How to add/insert element in array one after another like stack swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I get String from api response and stored in an array.

```
     for customParams in custom_attributes! {
         if(customParams["attribute_code"] as! String == "small_image") 
        {
         print(customParams["value"])
         var myString = customParams["value"] as! String

         //want to add this myString in array(myArray) one after another
         var myArray :[String] = []
              print(myArray)      
        }
 }
```

Output:

```
myArray = ["myString1","myString2"......]
```

How do I do it guys? I'm still new to swift... Thanks in advance!

```
"id": 6,
"products": {
"items": [{
"status": 1,
"custom_attributes": [
{
{
"attribute_code": "small_image",
"value": "small_image"
},
{
"attribute_code": "meta_keyword",
"value": "meta_keyword"
}]},
{
"status": 1,
"custom_attributes": [
{
{
"attribute_code": "small_image",
"value": "small_image"
},
{
"attribute_code": "meta_keyword",
"value": "meta_keyword"
}
]}]}}]
```

want to fetch customParams["attribute_code"] == small_image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the items array first as it is in json, also declare myArray outside the for loop and start appending myString inside myArray as shown:

```
var myArray :[String] = []
for custom_attributes! in items { // items is the json items array
    for customParams in custom_attributes! {
        if(customParams["attribute_code"] as! String == "small_image") 
             {
             print(customParams["value"])
             var myString = customParams["value"] as! String
             myArray.append(myString)

         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: you only want to store the values of `customParams["value"]` where `customParams["attribute_code"]` is `"small_image"`. Are you sure your condition is right?

Comment: I want to store customParams["value"] in array which came from array itself.

Comment: you have `"custom_attributes"` inside `items` array. Are you looping though `items` also?

Comment: answer updated adding one more for loop for `items`

Comment: that's what I tried earlier,but it doesn't work ..store only one value

Comment: Maybe you tried earlier with myArray declared inside the for loop, put it outside and try again.

Comment: @Prajakta great!

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray :[String] = []

for customParams in custom_attributes! {    
    if(customParams["attribute_code"] as! String == "small_image") {
         var myString = customParams["value"] as! String
         myArray.append(myString)
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share your JSON Data?

Comment: I share my Json

Comment: Please share your complete code which you used fatching data