# How to create array of array using for loop in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create array of array

ex-

```
let myImages: [[String]] = [

    ["image_url_0_0", "image_url_0_1", "image_url_0_2", "image_url_0_3"],

    ["image_url_1_0", "image_url_1_1", "image_url_1_2"],

    ["image_url_2_0", "image_url_2_1", "image_url_2_2", "image_url_2_3", "image_url_2_4"]
]
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work perfectly.

```
var myArray :[[String]] = []

for custom_attributes! in items { // items is the json items array
    var arrImage: [String] = []
    for customParams in custom_attributes! {

        if let attCode = customParams["attribute_code"] as? String, attCode == "small_image"   {
             print(customParams["value"])

             var myString = customParams["value"] as! String
             arrImage.append(myString)
         }

     }
     myArray.append(arrImage)
 }
```

But I get result in this form

```
[["image_url_0_0"], ["image_url_0_0","image_url_0_1"], ["image_url_0_0","image_url_0_1","image_url_0_3"].....]
```

How should I do this?Please Help.

Comment: Paste your json in question.

Comment: intialize your array like that var myArray :[[String]] = [[:]]

Comment: You are not getting any correct answers (so far) so as already requested, show us a sample of your input data so we understand what to work with.

Comment: @-Joakim Danielson, [
{
"id": 6,
"products": {
"items": 
[
{
"custom_attributes": [
{
"attribute_code": "small_image",
"value": "small_image"
}
]
},
{

"custom_attributes": [
{
"attribute_code": "small_image",
"value": "small_image"
}
]
}
]
}
}
] this is my Json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add/insert element in array one after another like stack swift 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58198403/how-to-add-insert-element-in-array-one-after-another-like-stack-swift-5). As you can see someone posted a question with exactly the same Json data already.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create simple string array and then append this array to your myArray. Check following code may be it's help

```
var myArray :[[String]] = []

for custom_attributes! in items { // items is the json items array
    var arrImage: [String] = []
    for customParams in custom_attributes! {

        if let attCode = customParams["attribute_code"] as? String, attCode == "small_image"   {
             print(customParams["value"])

             var myString = customParams["value"] as! String
             arrImage.append(myString)
         }

     }
     myArray.append(arrImage)
 }
```

Comment: Hey it didnt work.it gives me result [

    ["image_url_0_0", "image_url_0_1", "image_url_0_2", "image_url_0_3"],

    ["image_url_1_0", "image_url_1_1", "image_url_1_2"],

    ["image_url_0_0", "image_url_0_1", "image_url_0_2", "image_url_0_3""image_url_2_0", "image_url_2_1", "image_url_2_2", "image_url_2_3", "image_url_2_4"]
]

Comment: This is array of array and it's same as your example in your post

Comment: hey it adds previous data into next and so on..so in last array of arrray it contain all the data.you can see it in my question

Answer (score 0):

You try this

```
var myArray :[[String]] = []

for custom_attributes! in items { // items is the json items array
     let arr : [String] = []
    for customParams in custom_attributes! {

        if(customParams["attribute_code"] as! String == "small_image") 
             {
             print(customParams["value"])

             var myString = customParams["value"] as! String

             arr.append(myString)
         }

     }
myArray.append(arr)

 }
```

Comment: hey it didnt work. it add previous data into next array and so on.